# How to use Bootstrap Popover with Angular2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, popover

I am trying to get a Bootstrap 3 popover to display an Angular 2 interpolated template. Is this possible? Here is what I have so far:

```
    $('.ba-header--user-menu').popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      toggle: 'popover',
      trigger: 'focus',
      html: true,
      content: '{{user.email}}'
    });
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the plunkr? Bootstrap and external JS files do have know issues here. Even I am facing similar issues with Bootstrap and data-toggles. Some work out of box and some dont.

Comment: Much better to get rid of `bootstrap.js` and use `angular-ui-bootstrap` but if you want to continue you need to initialize jquery plugins in directives to assure element exists when code is run. As for compiling `interpolation` braces that won't happen...get content  in directive

Comment: I am under the impression angular-ui-bootstrap for angular2 is called https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/core and only supports 3 components atm. Unfortunately, popover doesn't seem to be one of them

Comment: why dont you try angular ui bootstrap. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: github.com/ng-bootstrap/core was renamed to https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap and now supports 13 components (and new features are added almost every day!). Popover is part of the supported directives now.

Comment: @Naga2Raja we are talking about Angular 2 and Bootstrap 3 here

Answer (score 12):

JQuery and Angular don't play very well together. Install [ng2-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-popover):

```
npm i ng2-popover
```

and use it like this:

```
<span popover="content to be shown in the popover">
    element on which this popover is applied.
</span>
```

Comment: there is a bunch of issues. Before self promoting please fix them https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-popover/issues

Comment: its not promotion, its a help. Its a simple component that shows how popover works, there is nothing that I can promote. You got this help for free, if you dont like something send a PR, contribute, or create a fork and maintain your own version

Comment: @pleerock I am getting Error: (SystemJS) ctorParameters.map is not a function. though my angular version is 2.1.2. Could you please suggest what could be causing this?

Comment: Looks a good solution. But I get the same error (ctorParameters.map is not a function) as @angular2

Comment: Yoy! Thank you! Bootstrap popover worked with angular's 2 ngModel! look to https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/popover "Dynamic HTML"

Answer (score 2):

You can also try a library I published [ng2-pop-over](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pop-over) (not to be confused with ng2-popover mentioned above). It is compact and you'll have to add your styles but has what it takes to solve your problem without jQuery.

Comment: I get the exact same error - "ctorParameters.map is not a function" when I try ng2-popover and ng2-pop-over. Maybe something I'm doing wrong. I checked and there seems to be stuff about Angular version. I even ran the npm update. Nothing improved.

Comment: It is possible to display the ng2-pop-over programatically? I don't see any documentation on that.

Comment: Yes it is, look for the word "Programmatically" and you'll see an example

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible but you cannot call interpoleted symbol into jQuery plugin the way you are doing.
you have to assign your dynamic email directly using `this` like this.

```
ngOnInit(){
   $('#abc').popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      toggle: 'popover',
      title: 'khcksahkdfs'
      html: true,
      content: this.name
    });
 }

 <a id="abc">Toggle popover</a>
```

working [Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GtGaJa4cJr5P2bkmbok7)

Comment: But in this case Angular2 (click) directive will not work inside popover html, becouse jquery is clone popover htmland then show it on browser.

Comment: For those using webpack, add const $ = require('jquery'); to use jquery shortcut $.

Comment: how did u import popover ? ng is not compiling.. nvm, missed to do `npm install --save @types/bootstrap`

Comment: I am not sure right now, but you don't need to import `@type/bootstrap` for same, instead you have to declare `$` of `any` type on the top of your component. and popover will be used using bootstrap.js mentioned in your angular-cli.json file.