# Console is showing "require is not defined" error

Tags: angular

I am trying to install [ngx-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-popover) (by the way the files I get from npm install are different from the ones in github)

This the file structure

[image]

and this is how I add it in the angular-cli.json

[image]

Now the problem is that, in the console its giving me errors saying
*"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"*

[image]

Do I need to add require.js ? 
[Also this question seems to be similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730010/angular2-5-minute-install-bug-require-is-not-defined), but I could not find `module: commonjs` anywhere.

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: you can use `ng-bootstrap` popup module instead.

Comment: For future references, this is the answer from where I got the pop up  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37868798/5936814

Comment: @Aravind Its in alpha I cannot use that in production

Comment: Did you have @types/node node module and reference in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed using the typescript version of it